# PHPExcel multisheet

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have a site where I want to create a report file with PHPExcel.
I make two cycle one for the first sheet where I have a week summary, and another cycle for every day of the week.
I retrieve this error with my script:

```
Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter() must be an instance of PHPExcel, null given, called in /var/www/reports/generate_reports_settimanale.php on line 79 and defined in /var/www/inc/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php on line 132
```

This is my simplified code:

```
require_once '../inc/PHPExcel.php';
require_once '../inc/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

        // Set document properties
        $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("Alessandro Minoccheri")
                                     ->setLastModifiedBy("Alessandro Minoccheri")
                                     ->setTitle("Office 2007 XLSX Test Document")
                                     ->setSubject("Office 2007 XLSX Test Document")
                                     ->setDescription("Generazione report inverter")
                                     ->setKeywords("office 2007 openxml php")
                                     ->setCategory("");

        $row=1;
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow('0', $row, 'Inverter');
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow('1', $row, 'Channel');


            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow('0', 1, 'inverter');
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow('1', 1, 'channel');

            $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
        $objWriter3 = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel3, 'Excel5');

            $week_end = date( 'Y-m-d 23:59:59', $start + ( 6 * 86400 ) );
            $week_start = date( 'Y-m-d 00:00:00', $start );
            $date = $week_start;
        while (strtotime($date) <= strtotime($week_end)) {
            $date = date ("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($date)));
            $objWorkSheet = $objPHPExcel->createSheet($date); //Setting index when creating

            //Write cells
            $objWorkSheet->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello'.$i)
                    ->setCellValue('B2', 'world!')
                    ->setCellValue('C1', 'Hello')
                    ->setCellValue('D2', 'world!');

            // Rename sheet
            $objWorkSheet->setTitle("test");
        }

            header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="report.xls"');
        header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
        $objWriter3->save('php://output');
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
 $objWriter3 = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel3, 'Excel5');
```

As the error says... $objPHPExcel3 doesn't exist yet. So far you've only used $objPHPExcel in your script. You're sending it a NULL value. (And upon reviewing the code I don't see you ever create a $objPHPExcel3)

Comment: Mine error +1 for the quicly answer as soon as possible I accept the answer thanks

Comment: You're welcome :) By the way, a good IDE like NetBeans would have pointed it out ;) I resisted using a full IDE for years and after a few months it's soooo worth it.